# Fix only one element of a row at the right side, and others should scroll

Tags: css

```css
.custom-container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 80px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="item">....</div>
        <div class="item">....</div>
        <div class="item">....</div>
        <div class="item">....</div>
        <div class="item">....</div>
        <div class="item">....</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Let's say overflow case occurs when there are 4 items present in the custom-container., 
But I need the first element(item) to be fixed at the right end of the custom container, and the rest should be able to scroll.

Comment: Could you specify a bit more? If I understood your question correctly a float right on the first item should do it.

Comment: yeah, sure. Let's say we have a horizontal tab(div with width>height) like the StackOverflow comment box, 
suppose it can have 4 items(say 4 images each of size 100px x 100px), and I need to  add more images to the same division so that overflow will occur and I will have to scroll to see the rest of the images, 
But I need my first image to be fixed at the right end of the tab (div) and only the rest should be scrolled(in the case of overflow)
how can I implement that? This is my question.!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code for a horizontal scroll version. The same concept but just make items inline-block so they don't take 100% of the width and set the whitespace of the container to nowrap so they're side by side.

```css
body{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.container-overflow{
  padding: 100px 0;
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.item{
  width: 150px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#fixed{
  position: fixed;
  left: 400px;
  top: 100px;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-overflow">
  <div class="item" id='fixed'></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

You cant have an element fixed relative to its parent unless the parent is the window. But if you know the width of the parent element and the width of the fixed element you can use the CSS transform property to position it where you want.

```css
body{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.overflow-container{
  margin-top: 100px;
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: #000;
}

.items{
  height: 90px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100px;
}

#right{
  background-color: blue;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(100px) translateX(400px);
}
```

```html
<div class="overflow-container">
  <div class="items" id="right"></div>
  <div class="items"></div>
  <div class="items"></div>
  <div class="items"></div>
  <div class="items"></div>
  <div class="items"></div>
  <div class="items"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks good, but there are some issues here too, In your example, I need to fix the blue element, that's looking good here, but also the red items should align horizontally, and they have to scroll horizontally too. here you have done a vertical scroll